# msmtp error: errormsg='the server sent an empty reply' exitcode=EX_PROTOCOL

Tags: socks, msmtp

I see this error message in the log of msmtp. What does it mean? How to fix the problem?

I previous used tor's socks proxy and I don't see this message. But when I switch the proxy to a shadowsocks localhost port, I see this error.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same snag.  Your problem is quite possibly something else, though.  I hadn't realized that msmtp uses STARTLS by default and that's not something that works with my mail provider, so `tls_starttls off` did the trick for me.